# Filter the output in json format in ansible playbook

Tags: json, ansible

I have a json file as below

```
"data": [

   {
      "name": "first",
      "foo": "123",
      "item": "monday"
  },

  {
      "name": "second",
      "foo": "456",
      "item": "tuesday"
      },

      { 
      "name": "third",
      "foo": "789",
      "item": "wednesday"}

  ]
}
```

Now I need the value of foo when item is wednesday in my ansible playbook

I used the below json query but failed to get desired output

```
- name: Get foo value.
  set_fact:
     foo_value: "{{ (json.stdout | from_json).data | map(attribute='foo') | list }}"
```

I need `foo_value : 789` when I mention `item : wednesday`, please let me know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

> I need `foo_value : 789` when I mention `item : wednesday`, please let me know what I am doing wrong

The first thing you are doing wrong is the failure to mention `item` anywhere in your expression; that said, what you are looking for is [`selectattr`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#selectattr)

```
set_fact:
  foo_value: "{{ (json.stdout | from_json).data
    | selectattr('item', 'eq', 'wednesday')
    | map(attribute='foo') | list }}"
```